# Grammar for prime length strings

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

How do we write an unrestricted grammar for
$$L = \{a^n \ | \ n \ \text{is prime}\}$$

I know that $L$ is neither regular, nor context-free.

Also, I know how to build a Turing Machine for $L$. The idea is to use two tapes, one having $n$ ones, and the other having $m$ ones. The TM checks if $m$ divides $n$. If it does, the string is rejected. Else, the TM continues with $m+1$ (until $m=n$, in which case the string is accepted). $\varepsilon$ or $a^1$ can be handled separately.
So one way to build the grammar is to encode all transitions of this TM.

Is there a more intuitive way? (say, that doesn't involve writing rules from the TM)

Comment: How about the sieve of Eratosthenes?

Comment: @Pål Grammar from the TM for that? That would work, but I am more interested in coming up with a grammar itself.

Comment: @PålGD: the sieve produces all primes *up to a preset limit*, but the desired grammar must be able to generate an arbitrarily large prime. And it does not need to be deterministic.

Comment: @rici Not sure if that's a problem. We can always choose this preset limit to be arbitrarily large, printing it in the initial steps of generation.

Comment: @abs: I guess so. But doing an entire sieve just to emit a single valid string seems unnecessarily complicated. But whatever works, really.

Comment: @rici Indeed, I posted this question in want for a less complicated (and more intuitive) method.